# Pixelate image, pick the printable (Pantone) colors from it with PHP?

Tags: php, image-processing

I would like to pixelate an image and list all the colors in the image with their Pantone value so that I can superimpose the image on tiles and print them.

So far, the pixelation is done, no problem. But how can the colors in the image be listed and their Pantone(closest) values be extracted? I cannot find any reference to this. Any existing classes/libraries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a JSON of the **Pantone** colour names [here](https://github.com/Margaret2/pantone-colors/blob/master/pantone-numbers.json) with their corresponding hex values. I do not know if it subject to copyright or how up-to-date it is.

I presume you could use a CIE Lab colour difference formula from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#CIE94) to work out the nearest one.

Comment: I am not that big of a math-ninja. Any library available to take care of the color difference easily? The first part  I can take care.

Comment: PHP is not looking so popular nowadays... you could maybe use the CIE94 Delta code from here... https://github.com/danmichaelo/php-coma